# How to design a "View" in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a XAML design in Xamarin android and I want to use it in Xamarin forms.
How could I do that?
this is my XAML code in Xamarin android:

```
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
class="mono.samples.notepad.LinedEditText"
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:gravity="top"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:capitalize="sentences"
/>
```

Comment: EditText in Android corresponds Entry in Xamarin.forms.Refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Xamarin.Android app to Xamarin.Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101664/migrate-xamarin-android-app-to-xamarin-forms-app)

Answer (score 0):

This is not XAML, this is XML. There is no direct way to support Android XML layouts in Xamarin.Forms (which makes sense as they couldn't work on iOS). You may try to do it with some custom renders, but those will work only on Android.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a XAML design in Xamarin android and I want to use it in Xamarin forms
>   How could I do that?

[Android XML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_ui_design.htm) and [Xamarin Xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/) are not the same, they are both different specs of XML and cannot be used in place of each other.

> This is my XAML code in Xamarin android:

That is XML and not XAML as you read above, also I have suggested a duplicate above see if that works for you or not